# strftime and setlocale compatibility

Tags: php

The manual says php 4,5 for strftime and setlocale.

Does a user need any special extensions to use these? For example I have seen php 5.2 json_encode not work because it was an extension.

I am developing an application that needs to work on many php 5 installations. I want to make sure these functions will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extension for these, **but** you have to keep in mind that they are extremely server-dependent (you really cannot assume much about which locales will be available).

If you are shooting for portability IMHO you should ditch the locale-related functions entirely.

Comment: Thank you...What are the alternatives?

Comment: @ChrisMuench: Primarily elbow grease. :)

Comment: Do you mean I will have to translate dates manually I create my own functions?

Comment: @ChrisMuench: Either that, or borrow the appropriate code from some project (e.g. an application framework) with a suitably permissive license and adapt it. You shouldn't have to search very much.